# I have enabled public access in cloud run. how to secure the endpoint URL? Using this cloud run in my workflow

Tags: security, workflow, google-cloud-run, service-accounts

I have a cloud run and I am using the endpoint URL of cloud run in various steps of the workflow. I have allowed unauthorized access for my cloud run. I want to secure my endpoint URL. what is the best way to do so? I am not able to find a proper way to do secure my cloud run endpoint URL.

I tried using JWT token but it expires in 1-10 hours, so I cannot use it as my workflow will fail if it runs more that 10 hours. Is there a way to secure my cloud run through service account json key, So,that whoever has this key only they can access or run the workflow? or is there any better way?